# Como recuperar o segundo texto em uma validação com AssertEquals

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assert

Tenho esse código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E estou tentando recuperar o texto "Teste_Automacao".

aí fiz o seguinte código.

```
WebElement idMenu = navegador.findElement(By.id("dropdown-menu-profile"));
String valortesteAutomacao = idMenu.getText();
assertEquals("Teste_Automacao", valortesteAutomacao);
```

porém só me aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já tentei por Xphat, porém o mesmo não retorna....

Como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui fazer:

É o seguinte, no caso, eu tinha que navegar entre todos os Pais, para chegar onte queria. Então usei 3 tipos de By (id, className, tagName).
Eu só não sabia do tagName, que era o que estava faltando antes.
Assim, não precisei usar o xPhat.

```
WebElement testeAutomacao = navegador.findElement(By.id("dropdown-menu-profile"));
WebElement idMenu = testeAutomacao.findElement(By.className("user-data"));
String valortesteAutomacao = idMenu.findElement(By.tagName("p")).getText();
assertEquals("Teste_Automacao", valortesteAutomacao);
idMenu.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua busca está incorreta, ao capturar pelo id dropdown-menu-profile você está pegando o texto inteiro da div.Para pegar apenas o texto do parágrafo você precisaria ser mais específico, pegando os elementos filhos da div ou então usando o xpath. Exemplo de xpath:

```
//div[@id='dropdown-menu-profile']//p
```

Comment: Então, fiz desta forma também, porém o "valortesteAutomacao" fica vazio. Como posso fazer? Eu tentei pegar a DIV filha também, mas não consigo recuperar o texto que preciso. Somente o que está dentro dela.

Comment: pra pegar todos elementos filhos você pode fazer o seguinte: 
List<WebElement> filhos = idMenu.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
no entanto essa aproximação de ir pegando os filhos é meio custosa, com o xpath você poderia pegar bem mais facilmente, se você tem duvidas do que seu xpath está retornando, você pode dar um ctrl+f na aba elements do console de desenvolvedor do chrome e testar por lá pra ver o que seu xpath está pegando